# Have an issue with bootstrap modal popup box

Tags: jquery

I have a issue with jquery version, previously i added the https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js, so the modal popup have no issue, but recently i modified the jquery version and added https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js as per requirement, so i got the error, modal popup is not responding properly. Here is my code :

```
<div class="row pd-top-20">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
<a class="card-link" href="#" data-title="Sandy" data-target="#audio-moa" data-toggle="modal" src="#">
<div class="card mb-3 border-light shadow-sm rounded">
<div class="row no-gutters">
<div class="col-md-4">
<img src="#" class="card-img" alt="...">
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="card-body">
<h5 class="card-title">Sandy</h5>
<p class="card-text">
<em>WMUK</em>
</p>
<p>Waldenström’s Macroglobulinemia</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Whats the difference between `previously added` and `recently added` in your question ?

Comment: my old code have jquery 3.3.1 and now trying to modified with 3.5.1 :) @AlwaysHelping

Comment: Your question says 3.5.1 and 3.5.1 => is that a typo ?

Comment: yes version of the jquery

Comment: please share the console error or share the modal code

Comment: Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity '4+XzXVhsDmqanXGHaHvgh1gMQKX40OUvDEBTu8JcmNs='. The resource has been blocked.
@PrinjuKoshyVaidyan

Comment: remove the integrity tag <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"  ></script>

Comment: Thanks a lot @PrinjuKoshyVaidyan issue was solved after removing the integrity tag :D

Answer (score 1):

The issue was when changing the source URL but not changing the integrity tag of the previous one..
Removal of that integrity tag will help you